# How to validate phone number using PHP?

Tags: php, regex

How to validate phone number using php

Comment: Please define what makes a phone number *valid*?

Comment: your missing the other planets..

Comment: In my country they don't. Plus there might be an international prefix. Or an extension. Depending on the country, digit groups get distanced with spaces, dots or dashes. Ergo: Validation is culture dependend and not quite as simple as you think.

Comment: is this an Australian phone number, a UK number, an international number, etc, etc? Validating phone numbers from around the world can open up more worms than email validation - and I don't think I've ever seen that done 100% infallible.

Comment: @christian: You forgot pause signals.

Comment: since when did 'phone number start with a tilde ?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation

Comment: Best solution is to use libphonenumber which is a port of Google's libphonenumber to PHP https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php

Comment: It's not good this topic was closed in favor of topic about phone number regexps, because it suggest there is no better way to achieve this. And there are many. For PHP right now the most straightforward way is to use this library: https://github.com/brick/phonenumber

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Since phone numbers must conform to a pattern, you can use regular expressions to match the entered phone number against the pattern you define in regexp.

php has both ereg and preg_match() functions. I'd suggest using preg_match() as there's more documentation for this style of regex.

An example

```
$phone = '000-0000-0000';

if(preg_match("/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}$/", $phone)) {
  // $phone is valid
}
```

Comment: and people who put brackets around their area code?   (202) 555 1212

Comment: Forcing a particular formatting convention is insane. You also need to handle international dialling prefixes.

Comment: That should be a {3} in the middle of the preg_match, right?  Not a {4}.  At least for US phone numbers.

Comment: This is not a thorough regex for phone numbers. There are dozens of ways phone numbers can be formatted especially including international numbers.

Comment: Depending on what they're working on, they might not need international support.

Comment: this is not enough, there are many other valid number formats

Comment: you are forcing a set format this is just bad programming.

Comment: Here is a regular expression for US phone numbers with optional 1 at the front and optional parens, also accepts - or . or ' ' between numbers or no spacer: 
^1?[-. ]?\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$  
I think the number of digits in the regular expression of the accepted answer is off XXX-XXXX-XXXX second {N} should be 3.

Answer (score 41):

Here's how I find valid 10-digit US phone numbers. At this point I'm assuming the user wants my content so the numbers themselves are trusted. I'm using in an app that ultimately sends an SMS message so I just want the raw numbers no matter what. Formatting can always be added later

```
//eliminate every char except 0-9
$justNums = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $string);

//eliminate leading 1 if its there
if (strlen($justNums) == 11) $justNums = preg_replace("/^1/", '',$justNums);

//if we have 10 digits left, it's probably valid.
if (strlen($justNums) == 10) $isPhoneNum = true;
```

Edit: I ended up having to port this to Java, if anyone's interested. It runs on every keystroke so I tried to keep it fairly light:

```
boolean isPhoneNum = false;
if (str.length() >= 10 && str.length() <= 14 ) { 
  //14: (###) ###-####
  //eliminate every char except 0-9
  str = str.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");

  //remove leading 1 if it's there
  if (str.length() == 11) str = str.replaceAll("^1", "");

  isPhoneNum = str.length() == 10;
}
Log.d("ISPHONENUM", String.valueOf(isPhoneNum));
```

Comment: what if entered number is +1981878978

Comment: @Bugfixer It only removes the leading 1 if the length is 11.

Comment: Was able to use this with some alterations. thank you for making your answer direct.

Answer (score 17):

I depends heavily on which number formats you aim to support, and how strict you want to enforce number grouping, use of whitespace and other separators etc....

Take a look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation/) to get some ideas.

Then there is [E.164](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E.164) which is a numbering standard recommendation from [ITU-T](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITU-T)