# How to use input type="tel" in a contact form

Tags: php, html, contact-form

PHP newbie here trying to use a simple contact form. The fields I have are: "Name", "Email", "Phone", and "Message". I am trying to figure out what to do with the "Phone" field – I want it to output to the same place that "Message" does, so that when the email is received it will output both the message and the phone number to the body of the email. How do I do this?

```
    if( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) : 
        wp_mail( get_option( 'admin_email' ), 
        'Website Contact Form',
        ( isset($_POST['message'] ) ? $_POST['message'] : '(blank)' ), 
        'From: ' . ( isset( $_POST['from_name'] ) ? $_POST['from_name'] : 'Website Contact Form' ) . ' <' . ( isset( $_POST['from_email'] ) ? $_POST['from_email'] : get_option( 'admin_email' ) ). '>' . "\r\n" );
    $output = '<p>Thank you! Your message has been sent.</p>'; 
    else : 
        $output = '
<form action="" method="post"><ul>
    <li>
        <label for="from_name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" name="from_name" id="from_name" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="from_email">Email</label>
        <input type="email" name="from_email" id="from_email" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="from_tel">Phone</label>
        <input type="tel" name="from_tel" id="from_tel" />
    </li>
    <li>
        <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea>
    </li>
    <li class="submit">
        <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Say Hello!" />
    </li>
</ul></form>';
    endif;
    return $output;
```

Answer (score 0):

there's nothing like `type=tel`, just use `type=text` and validate it for only numbers, after removing hyphens, braces etc. if any.

```
$_POST['tel'] = str_replace(array('-','(',')', ' ', '+'), '', $_POST['tel']);
if( is_numeric($_POST['tel']) === FALSE )
  echo 'Telephone # should consist of only numbers.';
```

Comment: HTML5 comes with [type=tel](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Or, use three input type=text

```
(____) ___ - _____
```

and merge them together with php.

Answer (score 0):

You can validate your phone number with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090862/how-to-validate-phone-number-using-php).

On the front-end, you can use a [JavaScript mask](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/javascript-input-masks/) to make your input field look sexy.