# Submitting an HTML form into a PHP form check

Tags: php, html, forms

So right now I'm attempting to create an HTML file that takes user phone number and then checks the input's format via PHP form checking. I've been trying to figure this out but I'm still not clear on what the format for an int with specified parameters would be.

(Duplicate question but different enough to say it's just some copy of other questions. Same question, different methods, different answers.)

My code: 
(Made a comment in the code where I'm uncertain what to do.)

```
if($_POST && isset($_POST['submit'], $_POST['name'], $_POST['phone'])) {

$name = $_POST['name'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];

if(!$name) {
    $errorMsg = "Please enter your name";
} elseif(!$phone || !preg match("\d{3}[\-]\d{7}", $email)){//this line format is incorrect
    $errorMsg = "Please enter a valid phone number";
    exit;
}
?>

<html>
<body>
<form method="POST">

Name:<br>
<input type="text" name="name">
<br>

Phone:<br>
<input type="tel"
pattern="\d{3}[\-]\d{7}"
title="Phone Number (Format: 999-9999999)"
name="phone">

<input name="submit" type="submit" value="submit">


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if your form submit to the current page itself, you can actually take off the action attribute in your form

Comment: Are you really missing a `_` between `preg` and `match`?  Also, `$email` is not defined, did you mean `$phone`?

Comment: @Andrew Thanks! I didn't know that, I fixed that as well.

Comment: regexp pattern should be enclosed in `/` or `#` - `preg_match("/\d{3}[\-]\d{7}/", $phone)`

Comment: @u_mulder:  Whaaaaa!  We all missed that.

Comment: @u_mulder Ah! Ok see that's what I wasn't sure about. I was using that format and didn't know if PHP accepted it. Thank you much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Editing form to sanitize/validate phone number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15978667/editing-form-to-sanitize-validate-phone-number)

Comment: @dev0 would that effect it though?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the `_` in `preg_match()` and the delimiters for preg_match and you had the variable `$email` in preg_match instead of `$phone`. I also added if phone isn't 11 char cause the regex you had would allow trailing chars.

```
if(!$name) {
    $errorMsg = "Please enter your name";
} elseif(!$phone || !preg_match('~\d{3}[\-]\d{7}~', $phone) || strlen($phone) != 11){//this line format is incorrect
    $errorMsg = "Please enter a valid phone number";
    exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> regexp pattern should be enclosed in / or # -
>   preg_match("/\d{3}[-]\d{7}/", $phone)

*– u_mulder*

This guy answered my question.