# How can i validate integer form in php?

Tags: php

I want to validate integer form using PHP. Do anyone of you know how to validate it?
my code like this 
`
          Thông tin thành viên
            ">

```
        <tr><td>First name : </td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="firstname"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Last name : </td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="lastname" /></td></tr>
        <tr><td>User Name: </td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="username"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Password: </td><td><input type="password" class="form-control" name="password"></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Email: </td><td><input type="email" class="form-control" name="email"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Phone: </td><td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone"/></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Cấp độ : </td>
            <td>                
                <select class="form-control" name="level">
                    <option selected>---Free choose---</option>
                    <option value="1">Administrator</option>
                    <option value="0">Member</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td> <button type="submit" name="add" class="btn btn-primary btn-md">Thêm thành viên</button></td></tr>
    </table>`
```

When people input the phone i want to check whether it is integer or not? can you help?

Comment: Hi, have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090862/how-to-validate-phone-number-using-php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4100022/php-validate-integer

Comment: i did read both of them, but i can not understand, can you make it easier for me, i am just a beginer

Comment: $phone there is your POST phone

Comment: Please consider upvoting helpful answers to be thankful of time and effort people invest on your problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this is you want to check it on runtime.

```
<tr><td>Phone: </td><td><input type="number" class="form-control" name="phone"/></td></tr>
```

Or use `is_int` or `is_numeric` if you want to check the phone number after POST.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either:

```
is_int
```

or

```
is_numeric
```

Answer (score 0):

A safe attitude for the input validation process in php is like this for integer numbers:

**HTML form**

```
<input type="text" name="phone"/>
```

**PHP**

```
if( !filter_var( $_POST['phone'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) === false){
    echo("Variable is an integer");
}else{
    echo("Variable is not an integer");
}
```

Keep in mind that you can never trust the traffic originated from user, thus things like:

```
<input type="number" name="phone"/>
```

could not be the answer to this problem. You may use such methods to just help the end users fill-in your forms.