# Regex for this phone number?

Tags: php, regex

```
(00355) XX-XXX-XXXX
```

So far I have this but I don't know how to express that first five digits must be 00355.

```
/^.d{2}.\d{3}.\d{4}.$/
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A comprehensive regex for phone number validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation)

Comment: Also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3090862/how-to-validate-phone-number-using-php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/\(00355\)\s\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{3}/
```

should do the trick.

btw - try this tool: https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

In case you want to give the user more flexibility:

http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/i9u

```
preg_match("/(00355\s\d{2}[-|\s]\d{3}[-|\s]\d{4})/", $input, $output);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

`#^\(00355\) \d{2}-\d{3}-\d{4}$#`

https://regex101.com/r/d9ktJf/1

It will basicly check for string which starts with 00355 then has space then 2 numbers then `-` then 3 numbers then - and end with 4 numbers `#` is used as delimiter.